# Adding binary arrays with different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary

I made binary arrays from number and its bit length per line, if 295289042101659 with 6 bits per line, number sizes 49 bit so in array, it would be 6 bits X 9 line, through the code and modified to 6-length zero filled lines:

```
def listify(a, bit = 5):
    res = []
    while a:
        a, b = divmod(a,2**bit)
        res.append(b)
    return res[::-1]
```

000001
000011
001001
000001
010110
011101
011110
010110
011011

Since it is binary array, I used binary addition code without carrying:

```
def binaryadd(one, other):
    if one & other:
        return False
    return one | other
```

If I get some array of 402(0b110010010) with size 3, then how could I add into the array at point(2,2) by up-to-down coordinate, or (3,6) from down-to-up, right-to-left coordinate?
It should be seemed as:

000001
00**11**11
001**1**01
000**1**01
010110
011101
011110
010110
011011

I've done it like this:

```
def array_add(one,another, point = (0,0)):
    a = [a*2**point[0] for a in another[:]]
    a+=[0]*point[1]
    a = [0]*(len(one)-len(a))+a
    res = [binaryadd(a,b) for a, b in  zip(one[::-1],a[::-1])][::-1]
    if not all(res):
        return False
    return res
```

Is the best way to do it, is to apply binary addition to every values of list, by modifying one list?

Or am I misunderstanding the basics of array?

Comment: Hello. About `the best way` - almost any way is viable. It depends on the context and requirements. Right now context and requirements are unknown, rules of addition are unclear. Seems you get what you want with the code - `I've done it like this` - have you? Because this is wierd: `self = [0] * (len(block) - len(self)) + self`. Also, what happens to `fin_res` in `add` function? Does this code really work?

Comment: well, actually it gets end with return fin_res[::-1], but at first I have to correct the code independent; It has just copied from my class'attribute, so I have to correct all the expressions better to be understood; just wait for a while, please

Comment: @Poolka I've changed the code. 'a = [0b11111,0b10000,0b10000,0b10000];b = [ob11,0b10,0b10];array_add(a,b) =['0b11111','0b10011','0b10010','0b10010'] - is what I meant

Comment: Not sure what problem you are trying to solve and what result you expect. The code seems legit. Logic behind the code looks very simple while unclear (`point` and directions like `up-to-down coordinate`). Probably I would use just rows to store binaries in this case to start with. I guess the issue can be solved with numpy more efficiently using literally couple lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention the numpy tag, you can use it to have high performance and readable code :

```
import numpy as np

def int_to_array(n,width):
    v=np.zeros(64,np.uint8)
    i,u,total=0,n,0
    while(u):
      if i%width == 0 : total += width  
      u,v[i],i = u//2,u%2,i+1
    return v[:total][::-1].reshape(-1,width)  

def add(a,b,point=(0,0)):
    sx,sy = point
    ex = sx+b.shape[0]
    ey = sy+b.shape[1]
    a[sx:ex,sy:ey] |= b

a=int_to_array(295289042101659,6)
b=int_to_array(402,3)
print(a)
print(b)
add(a,b,(2,2))   
print(a)
```

For :

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1]]

[[1 1 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 0]]

[[0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: It works great except I've supposed the result False (not detecting out one & other), but I'd modify and test the performance. I totally agree it is really readable.